# convert double column to string column pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

hello guyes i have a datframe with double column (named double)
i want to convert it to StringType()
but when casting the column to string, all values  of double column trun to NULL

is there any trick to  convert double column  to string column ?

im using Pyspark 2.3

```
+------------------+--------------+------+----------+---------------------+----------------------+
|concat(", vide, ")|integer       |double|dt_arrete |concat(", vide_de, ")|code_lei|
+------------------+--------------+------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
|null              |10000000000000|1.1   |2021-06-30|null                 |"r"            |
|null              |1             |1.1   |2021-06-30|null                 |"code_lei"            |
|null              |1             |1.1   |2021-06-30|null                 |"code_lei"            |
|null              |1             |1.1   |2021-06-30|null                 |"code_lei"            |
|null              |2             |2.2   |2021-06-30|null                 |"code_lei"            |
|null              |2             |2.2   |2021-06-30|null                 |"code_lei"            |
|null              |2             |2.2   |2021-06-30|null                 |"code_lei"            |
|null              |2             |2.2   |2021-06-30|null                 |"code_lei"            |
+------------------+--------------+------+----------+---------------------+----------------------+
```

```
deptDF = deptDF.withColumn('double', F.col('double').cast('string'))
deptDF.show()
```

```
+------------------+--------------+------+----------+---------------------+----------------------+
|concat(", vide, ")|       integer|double| dt_arrete|concat(", vide_de, ")|code_lei
+------------------+--------------+------+----------+---------------------+----------------------+
|              null|10000000000000|  null|2021-06-30|                 null|            "code_lei"|
|              null|             1|  null|2021-06-30|                 null|            "code_lei"|
|              null|             1|  null|2021-06-30|                 null|            "code_lei"|
|              null|             1|  null|2021-06-30|                 null|            "code_lei"|
|              null|             2|  null|2021-06-30|                 null|            "code_lei"|
|              null|             2|  null|2021-06-30|                 null|            "code_lei"|
|              null|             2|  null|2021-06-30|                 null|            "code_lei"|
|              null|             2|  null|2021-06-30|                 null|            "code_lei"|
+------------------+--------------+------+----------+---------------------+----------------------+
```

Comment: Did you try: `deptDF = deptDF.withColumn('double', F.col('double').cast(StringType()))`

Comment: I did try it It does not work, to bypass this, i concatinated  the double column with quotes. so spark automatically convert it to string without loosing data , and then I removed the quotes. and i'v got numerics as string type
I will share the code tommoroe

Comment: @aminejisung I tried with both your code as well as one that @pissall advised, apparently both works for me on `Databricks`. By the way, which version of Spark are you using?

Comment: @dnky I am using pyspark 2.3

Comment: @aminejisung Pyspark 2.3

Comment: @aminejisung kindly share the code here